# Polar type chart with Highcharts plugin

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to make a polar type chart, which is similar to this:
http://star-board-sup.com/2015/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/11_6x30_astro_touring.png

Basically I have 4 values all ranging from 1-10 and would need them displayed in a fashion like above...so stretched out over the axis. Can you help me accomplish that using Highcharts? Looks similar to their polar type chart, but I can't figure out how to display it.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple try to rebuild your polar chart:
http://jsfiddle.net/c6unynr2/

This options should do most of your needs:

```
chart: {
    polar: true
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Tracking', 'Maneuverability', 'Stability', 'Speed'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0            
},

yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
},


series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Line',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}]
```